# In Nuxt, how do you pass data from layouts to pages?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

For example, in my `/layouts/sidebar.vue` I have the following code:

```
<template>
    <div class="mainContainer">
      <nuxt :date-sidebar="'This is from sidebar'"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

I want to pass the value of `date-sidebar` from layouts to `/pages/Request/index.vue` and eventually to `/components/RequestTable.vue` but I'm just currently testing it by passing static strings with the following code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <RequestTable :date-requested="'something'"/>
    {{ this.dateSidebar }} //data from sidebar that should receive something also tried just {{dateSidebar}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    props:['dateSidebar']
}
</script>
```

I can receive the static value from `/page/Request/index.vue` to my `/components/Request/RequestTable.vue` but I can't receive the data from the `/layouts/sidebar.vue` to my `/pages/Request/index`.

So my question as the title suggest would be, how do I pass `date-sidebar` from `/layouts/sidebar.vue` to `/pages/Request/index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this only works with `nuxt-link` (in pages so) as shown [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3234#issuecomment-414111504) and not `nuxt`

`pages/child.vue`

```html
<template>
  <nuxt-child :test="'RESOLVE_PLZ'"/>
</template>
```

`pages/child/index.vue`

```html
<script>
export default {
  props: ["test"],
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.test) // RESOLVE_PLZ
  }
}
</script>
```

It is kinda logical because the default layout is not really aimed towards this kind of usage. If you need something dynamic, it's usually going the other way around (emitting to the layout) or simply using Vuex (mainly because of not having to "emit up" several components up).

---

You could also do some hacky things like this

`child.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ dateSidebar }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    dateSidebar() {
      return this.$parent.$attrs['date-sidebar']
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

But this is not that common, hence probably not the way to do it.

Comment: according to the issue mentioned in the link you shared it is not possible to send data from the layouts to your pages unless you use store... I guess that's it, I might try the vuex or just separate the notification btn component from my layouts/sidebar.vue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `nuxtChildKey` props in your child properties. From the layout, bind the `nuxt-child-key` instead of `:date-sidebar`.

You may want to pass an object instead of a string so you can pass more data. So your `layout/sidebar` would look like...

```
<template>
    <div class="mainContainer">
      <nuxt :nuxt-child-key="'This is from sidebar'"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

On the child page...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <RequestTable :date-requested="'something'"/>
    {{ this.dateSidebar }} //data from sidebar that should receive something also tried just {{dateSidebar}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    props:['nuxtChildKey'], 
mounted(){
console.log(this.nuxtCHildKey, 'nck')
}
}
</script>
```

And there's a documentation available here... [nuxt-child-key](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components/)